# Encrypted on iPhone, but absolutely will not decrypt in php

Tags: iphone, encryption

ok

I'm using this to encrypt my data on iPhone:

```
- (NSData *)AES128EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key{

char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128 + 1]; // room for terminator (unused)
bzero( keyPtr, sizeof( keyPtr ) ); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

// fetch key data
[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof( keyPtr ) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

//See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or 
//equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
//That's why we need to add the size of one block here
size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
void *buffer = malloc( bufferSize );

size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt( kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionECBMode /*| kCCOptionPKCS7Padding*/,
                                      keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                      NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                      [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesEncrypted );
if( cryptStatus == kCCSuccess )
{
    //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
}

free( buffer ); //free the buffer
return nil;}
```

on my server my php script uses:

```
        $base64encoded_ciphertext = $pass;

    mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_decode($pass), 'ecb');

    $decrypted = $res_non;
    $dec_s2 = strlen($decrypted);

    $padding = ord($decrypted[$dec_s2-1]);
    $decrypted = substr($decrypted, 0, -$padding);
    return  $decrypted;
```

However, no matter what the key is, it fails.

The keys are always 10 characters long. I build a password using the system clock to get values.

On the php side I duplicate the key building and according to my script, the key ALWAYS matches what the iPhone used to encrypt.

This code worked in a different script, from a different app… and still works.
I've done a dead cut and paste of all related code and still nothing.

I just don't know what I'm doing wrong… beyond what I'm trying to do maybe being absolutely impossible

Comment: I hope you aren't storing this password in a database somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

For AES 128 you should use 16 byte Encryption key, AES 192 it is 24, AES 256 it is 32 byte. For your case you should use encryption key like @"1234567890123456".